# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar las líneas donde aparece una cadena de texto específica?

Tags: java, netbeans, file

Le he dado muchas vueltas y sólo he obtenido mostrar todas las lineas con sus saltos de línea.

```
public void leerLineas(File fichero/*, String cadena*/) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(fichero);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            //if(){}
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    } finally {
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //String cadena="hola";
    Actividad5 clase = new Actividad5();
    File fichero = new File("C:\\Users\\samue\\Desktop\\texto.txt");
    clase.leerLineas(fichero/*, cadena*/);
}
```

Comment: Hola Samu. Puedes explicar mejor lo que intentas? Pon ejemplos de el fichero y la busqueda que harias y el resultado esperado. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Samu,

Para mostrar sólo las líneas que contienen unas palabras especificas debes introducir un `if` en el `while` mirando que la línea contenga esa frase o palabras, de la siguiente forma:

```
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    String line=sc.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("frase que busco"))
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad :D Me estaba rayando muchísimo

Answer (score 3):

Como añadido a la respuesta de @Marc y usando `java-8`:

```
public void leerLineas(File fichero, String filtro) throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero)))
    {
        reader.lines().filter(linea -> linea.contains(filtro)).forEach(System.out::println);
    } 
}
```